# Differences between Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern

Tags: design-patterns

what is the difference between Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550700/inversion-of-control-vs-dependency-injection

Comment: The first ones implement the second one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'difference'. An Inversion of Control container can be used to create instances of classes, injecting any depencies needed via constructor, property or method injection.

Ultimately, the IoC container is the 'doer' and the injection is what's 'done'.

Read Mark Seemann's work for the full and clear picture.