# "Plugin" type logic that uses two assemblies

Tags: .net, design-patterns, architecture

I'm working on a migration tool. I have two different assemblies one is `Mapping` that is used to collect data and store it in predefined types (say `Customer`, `Product` etc).
That assembly is instanced in the Engine using reflection and the data is migrated to a destination platform (on a pretty hard coded way, we're having methods like `MigrateCustomers` and such).

I'd like to rewrite the application so it's more generic, allowing clients to (for example) extend our Product class, and inject logic into *both assemblies*. 
If it were only one I would make an interface, add `Execute()` method and it would be simple. (something like command pattern).

The problem is I need two make sure both assemblies use the same "plugin" - one part defines logic for getting the data the second for importing the data.

Is there a pattern that deals with similar issues?

Comment: That sounds like a job for the Managed Extensibility Framework, which is already built into .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patter to deal with this is called: Inversion of Control(IoC). You can refer these article for details:

1. [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)
2. [Inversion of Control vs Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550700/inversion-of-control-vs-dependency-injection)

[Managed Extensibility Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is based on IOC, if you want to implement a small plugin framework, you can follow the IoC pattern and do it your self; if you want to a framework with lots of features, you should use MEF.