# Design Pattern: Cache and Context

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection

A question about a design pattern.

I have a `DataManager` that uses a cache `DataCache` that is valid for a given context (in my case, a date).

Should my `DataCache` store the context under which the data cached is valid, or is it better to leave it only up to the `DataManager` to know when the `DataCache` needs to be reset?  I feel that having the Context in the Cache as well means more unnecessary maintenance, but maybe there is a good reason to have it in there.

A small point, but wondering what best practice would be here.

Example:

```
public class DataManager {
    DateTime context;
    DataCache cache;
}

public class DataCache {
    Dictionary dict;
}
```

or

```
public class DataManager {
    DateTime context;
    DataCache cache;
}

public class DataCache {
    DateTime context;  // note that we store the context here as well
    Dictionary dict;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `DataCache` can use the context internally to know it's invalid or reset itself or whatever, it should store it. The design priority here is to keep things simpler and safer for the users of a class (here the `DataCache` class), rather than reduce the internal work for the class.

Depending on the way the context is used, it can be stored only in the `DataCache` and the `DataManager` can access it with a getter.

Comment: so the answer is "whatever makes the most sense"

Comment: @gdbj it's more "users first", but "whatever makes the most sense" is a good motto too, even outside programming :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's cache's responsibility to invalidate data when it's expired, so ideally data cahe should keep track of context and invalidate. DataManager should query the Cache and if cache does not have data it should fetch data and update the cache.

Answer (score 0):

`Context` can be part of `Cache` if `Context` does not exists without `DataCache`.

You are creating dependencies  between `DataManager` and `DataCache`.

Replace `DataCache` with interface `IDataCache` so that you provide loose coupling. You can change `Cache` implementation in future with different class.

Have a look at these SE questions:

[What is dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection)

[Inversion of Control vs Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550700/inversion-of-control-vs-dependency-injection)