# IoC vs DIP differences

Tags: design-patterns, inversion-of-control, dependency-inversion

Is it possible to have Inversion of Control without the Dependency Inversion Principle? Some sources insist they're the same, others don't. Would like to get a conversation going around the differences.

Comment: DIP, IOC, and DI are all part of a [hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65588618/1371329).

Comment: @jaco0646 thanks, that's helpful