# Dependency Inversion vs Dependency Injection vs Inversion of Control

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am trying to find a proper explanation about the difference between Dependency Inversion, DI and IoC and read many articles to understand the difference like the following ones:

[Inversion of Control vs Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550700/inversion-of-control-vs-dependency-injection)

https://betterprogramming.pub/straightforward-simple-dependency-inversion-vs-dependency-injection-7d8c0d0ed28e

However, as I read a new articles and the answers on SO regarding to the issue, I am getting much more confused. Because, on [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.0/reference/html/core.html#beans-introduction), there is also the following clause for IoC:

> IoC is also known as dependency injection (DI)

So, could you please simply explain the differences between Dependency Inversion, Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control?

Comment: in spring documentation that you mentioned, they said : dependency injection and not Dependency Inversion.
So if you understand the difference between Dependency Inversion and IoC, you are good

Comment: @Idriss Are you sure that you read the question? I am afraid you did not read even the title and made some useless comment.

Comment: lol
according to spring : Dependency Injection = Inversion of Control. So we can discuss now this question : "Dependency Inversion vs Inversion of Control".  The second link that you mentioned explain all.

Comment: I can't promise that the Spring documentation strictly adheres to these definitions, but checkout these Wikipedia articles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle.

Answer (score 1):

**Dependency Injection** (DI) is a design practice to avoid strong coupling between
classes.

*Example A*

```
interface IB{}

Class B implements IB {}

Class A {
IB ib;

public A(IB ib){
this.ib = ib;
}
}
```

It is considered a dependency injection because ib can be anything that implements this interface. When you want to Test Class A you don't need to instantiate IB, or you can instantiate it with whatever you want. Bottom line, Class A doesn't depend strongly on ib (or class B)

**Inversion of Control** (IoC) is a concept where you, the developer, give the instantiation control to the framework (for example Spring). Hence, in a well-written code, you won't see the explicit invocation of constructors because the framework does it for you. IoC uses the DI design practice.

Let me know if you need a better clarification