Is the definition of "inversion of control" on wikipedia correct?

inversion of control (IoC) is a design principle in which
custom-written portions of a computer program receive the flow of
control from a generic framework.

The framework can be Java Spring Framework but we can also implement the inversion of control using:

Factory Pattern <- DEFINITELY NOT a framework
Strategy Pattern <- DEFINITELY NOT a framework
Events <- DEFINITELY NOT a framework
Dependency Injection <- NOT a framework
Service Locator <- NOT a framework

So why the definition of inversion of control on wikipedia is limited to a framework?

IoC is one way to remove your dependencies on concrete types. Look at SOLID principles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/may/csharp-best-practices-dangers-of-violating-solid-principles-in-csharp#the-dependency-inversion-principle

Dependency Injection is literally just another name for Inversion of Control.

In a regular program, the programmer himself decides in what sequence to make procedure calls. But if a framework is used, the programmer can place his code at specific points in execution (using callback or other mechanisms), then run the framework's "main function", which will handle all the execution and call the programmer's code when needed. As a result, there is a loss of control over the execution of the code - this is called inversion of control (the framework controls the programmer’s code, rather than the programmer controlling the framework).

I think you're interpreting the word "framework" in a much more specific manner than the Wikipedia article means it.  For the most part, WP seems to mean it quite generically. For IoC to work, there has to be something that is invoking methods on the objects provided by the application.  That "something" is the framework.

@David Conrad  no, Dependency Injection isn't the same as inversion of control

@JohnBollinger maybe you are right that here "framework" is something wider.

@AleksanderChelpski In every context I've ever heard them they are used interchangeably.

@David From my understanding, which may be wrong/incomplete, DI is simply the ability to pass dependencies to an object, whether via a constructor parameter, a method parameter, or directly setting a field. This can be done "manually" or "automatically". Manual DI does not use an IoC framework (it's just "normal" code). But automatic DI does require some kind of IoC framework that can create and pass objects for you (based on some configuration). In that context, I'm not surprised DI and IoC are used interchangeably, as most of the time it's "automatic DI" that's being discussed.

Wikipedia is often wrong about technical subjects, because it is routinely edited by non-technical authors. This answer may shed some light: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65588618/1371329.


"Is the definition of "inversion of control" on wikipedia correct?"

Yes, it is.
First of all, your list contains design patterns. A design pattern can't be a framework (because you were annotating your list with remarks that e.g. Factory pattern is not a framework to prove that the Wikipedia article is wrong). Of course, design patterns are not frameworks. And design patterns are not "implementations" of IoC. Frameworks use these design patterns to implement IoC.
The definition of a framework is clear. As you are using Wikipedia as a source, you can also use Wikipedia to lookup how it describes a framework:

"In computer programming, a software framework is an abstraction in which software, providing generic functionality, can be selectively changed by additional user-written code, thus providing application-specific software." Wikipedia

Now with this definition we can answer your question:

"So why the definition of inversion of control on wikipedia is limited to a framework?"

We have to differentiate between IoC and Dependency Inversion.
Writing code that depends on abstractions is following the Dependenc Inversion principle. It's not IoC.
Instantiating and injecting an implementation of an abstract type and managing the lifetime of that instance is Dependency Injection but still not IoC.
However, if the component that implements Dependency Inversion (to decouple client code from internal code) qualifies as a framework, in that it encapsulates generic functionality and behavior which is extensible via external code that is pre-defined as abstractions (Dependency Inversion) and invoked by that framework, then we call it IoC. That's simply the definition.
IoC is a special case of Dependency Inversion in that it focuses on the dependency between a library and its clients.
In other words, to make a library extensible with client code (i.e. modification or specialization of selective generic predefined functionality), we need to invert the control of the flow between components (client and library). Remember, a library is always called by client code: the control flow is from client to library. The idea of inverting this control flow is called IoC.
A library that has its control flow inverted, is called a framework. That means, IoC is not limited to frameworks, frameworks are the result of applied IoC.
A framework is a special form of a library (a collection of reusable functionalities and behaviors and other kinds of resources).
The main characteristic is that a framework implements design patterns to realize the Inversion of Control (IoC) principle. The control flow is reversed in that the specialized and extending code (client code, high-level code) is no longer calling the library code (low-level code). Instead, the framework calls the client code (low-level code calls high-level code). This should highlight that the focus is on controlling functionality and not dependencies.
The focus of IoC is on the extension of an encapsulated generic functionality/behavior where the low-level framework code calls high-level client code. The goal of IoC is not decoupling, although frameworks need to decouple their internals from externals.
The goal is the efficient extensibility and specializatrion of existing generic functionality/behavior.
All of your mentioned design patterns effectively help to invert the control of the flow or the caller callee relationship. However, implementing those design patterns like Dependency Injection alone doesn't make a library qualify as a framework.
You have (a) the generic functionality that can be (b) extended and specialized by plugging in custom/external code and that (c) does not need and allow modification in order to be extended/call client code. Following this definition, a framework can be a single class or thousands of classes. It depends on the functionality it provides.
A simple class that executes an operation on two operands (like a calculator) would also qualify as a framework, where you extend the functionality by providing the actual operations that the framework (the calculator) then executes (IoC). This calculator would create the expression trees and implement and ensure arithmetic rules, provide a history or undo/redo behavior etc. - the generic calculator functionality.
You now have a small calculator framework: "[...] generic functionality, [that] can be selectively changed by additional user-written code.", because of the inversion of the control flow (IoC).
Frameworks are nothing magical. They are just implementations of IoC. IoC is usually achieved by implementing certain design patterns. In other words, if you are able to implement IoC, you are always having a set of functionalities that qualify as a library. A library that applies IoC is a framework:

Frameworks have key distinguishing features that separate them from normal libraries:

inversion of control: In a framework, unlike in libraries or in standard user applications, the overall program's flow of control is not dictated by the caller, but by the framework. This is usually achieved with the Template Method Pattern.
default behavior [qualifies a library]: This can be provided with the invariant methods of the Template Method Pattern in an abstract class which is provided by the framework.
extensibility: A user can extend the framework–usually by selective overriding–or programmers can add specialized user code to provide specific functionality. This is usually achieved by a hook method in a subclass that overrides a template method in the superclass.
non-modifiable framework code: The framework code, in general, is not supposed to be modified, while accepting user-implemented extensions. In other words, users can extend the framework, but cannot modify its code.

Wikipedia


So a framework can be a class, IoC container or a library, yes?

Theoretically a class can be a framework if it follows the IoC principle. The definition of framework does not define how many classes it must be composed of. It's all about extensible generic functionality. Following other OO design principles, you likely end up having more than one class. An IoC container can be a framework if it satisfies the conditions. Applying IoC alone does not make a framework (see the list).

An IoC container usually follows the IoC principle, and can be considered itself a framework or part of a framework. In the end, an IoC container is a set of classes that are responsible for managing the registered dependencies. So, the answer to your first question (about classes) answers the second question about IoC containers.

A library is a library and not a framework. It's a library, the prestage of a framework. If the library follows the IoC principle (i.e. inverts the control flow) then it becomes a framework. I have posted the criteria that must be satisfied in order to call a component a framework (the last four points of the list).
